# function specialization based on if template parameter is shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to detect if a type is a `shared_ptr<T>` and if it is, dispatch to a specific function template or override.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm actually attempting:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

template <class T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T> > : std::true_type {};

class Foo { };
typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> SharedFoo;

template<class T> void getValue();

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_shared_ptr<T>::value>::type = 0>
void getValue()
{
    printf("shared!\n");
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!is_shared_ptr<T>::value>::type = 0>
void getValue()
{
    printf("not shared!\n");
}

int main(int, char **)
{
    getValue<SharedFoo>();
    getValue<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles just fine, but it seems the actual functions were never actually generated because the code doesn't link with the following errors:

```cpp
/tmp/ccjAKSBE.o: In function `main':
shared_test.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `void getValue<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>()'
shared_test.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `void getValue<Foo>()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would think that those would be covered by the two function templates. But they aren't.

Given that, it seems I am seriously misunderstanding something.

So maybe it would help if I explain what I'm /trying/ to do rather than what I'm actually doing.

I have some "magic" code using a bunch of new (to me) C++11 features to bind C++ code to lua (can be seen here: https://github.com/Tomasu/LuaGlue). someone has recently asked for support for binding to classes wrapped in `shared_ptr`'s. which is not something that works at the moment, because it binds at compile time using templates and tuple unwrapping to generate code to call functions on either the C++ or lua side. In the "magic" unwrapping code, I have a bunch of overridden and "specialized" functions that handle various variable types. Some for basic types, one for static objects, and another for pointer to objects. A `shared_ptr` can't be handled in the same way as either a static or pointer object, so I need to add some extra handling just for them.

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T getValue(LuaGlue &, lua_State *, unsigned int);

template<>
int getValue<int>(LuaGlue &, lua_State *state, unsigned int idx)
{
    return luaL_checkint(state, idx);
}

template<class T>
T getValue(LuaGlue &g, lua_State *state, unsigned int idx)
{
    return getValue_<T>(g, state, idx, std::is_pointer<T>());
}
```

That's the actual code (notice the hairy template/override via function argument :-x).

I had thought it'd be as simple as adding another `addValue` function, along the lines of the code in my earlier example, via `enable_if`.

Comment: You declare `template<class T> void getValue();` but don't define it. `template <typename, typename> void getValue();` is a different function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason not to simply use partial specialization?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

class Foo { };
typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> SharedFoo;

template <class T>
struct getValue {
    getValue() {
        printf("not shared!\n");
    }
};

template <class T>
struct getValue<std::shared_ptr<T> > {
    getValue() {
        printf("shared!\n");
    }
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    getValue<SharedFoo>();
    getValue<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other than my somewhat limited knowledge of template specialization and related mechanics no, not really. the code in general might be better suited by using partial specialization all over rather than function templates. I'm working on converting it all over and will see how it goes from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your program declares `template<class T> void getValue()` but doesn't define it. `template <typename, typename> void getValue()` is a different function. The compiler is picking `template<class T> void getValue()` as a better match with your invocations, which of course fails at link time as there is no definition of that function.

I prefer the simplicity of tag dispatch when it's applicable ([live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27494b8bc751cae2)):

```
template<class T>
void getValue(std::true_type)
{
    printf("shared!\n");
}

template<class T>
void getValue(std::false_type)
{
    printf("not shared!\n");
}

template<class T>
void getValue() {
    return getValue<T>(is_shared_ptr<T>{});
}
```

Comment: I was just about to say that I tried adding a second template parameter to the "default" method, but I never tried it as just a plane parameter, I tried both as: `typename... X` or `typename X = void` and both failed. But I just tried it plain, and it works as I was expecting. The part that makes this painful is some of my actual code is already using tag dispatch to handle pointer objects properly. so I think it'd get really messy to add in shared_ptr on top of that as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which is basically a fix for the OP rather than alternatives (using a class and its constructor as in zennehoy's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288855/1137388) or tag dispatch as in [Casey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289365/1137388)).

```
// Do not provide this declaration:
// template<class T> void getValue();

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_shared_ptr<T>::value>::type
getValue()
{
    printf("shared!\n");
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_shared_ptr<T>::value>::type
getValue()
{
    printf("not shared!\n");
}
```

I must say that, **as Casey has put it, I also "prefer the simplicity of tag dispatch"**. Hence, I would go for his solution.

I also found zennehoy's idea interesting but, unfortunately, it doesn't allow your function to return something. (I believe a workaround is possible but it adds complexity.) With the solution here you just need to provide the return type as the 2nd parameter of `std::enable_if`.

Comment: My current/old code actually uses some tag dispatch for detecting if a class type is a pointer or not, adding yet another tag would make things a little hairy in my book. Also I'm only somewhat basing my attempt on zeenohoy's example. I have three separate sets of functions to "fix", so I figured I'd put each set into their own class as static methods. One of the functions actually has to return a value as well.